# Accessible Sidebar menu

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag

Hello i am new to accessibility and i was checking a sidebar like component with axe dev tools, i got this issue: **Nested interactive controls are not announced by screen readers.**
i was wondering ho i could fix it as i dont understand how else to write it in order to make it accessible heres an example of the code

```html
<nav>
  <ul role="tablist" aria-label="menu">
    <li role="tab" aria-selected="true">
      <a tabindex="-1">Some link</a>
    </li>
   <li role="tab" aria-selected="true">
      <a tabindex="-1">Some link</a>
    </li>
    <li role="tab" aria-selected="true">
      <a tabindex="-1">Some link</a>
    </li>
  <ul>
<nav>
```

Comment: What are the nested interactive controls shown here?  And why do you have the `tabindex` on the anchors set to `"-1"`?

Answer (score 0):

A **tab** widget is considered an interactive element.  You click on one to switch tabs in a tab navigator.  Having a nested element within the tab (in your case, a link `<a>`) would be weird because clicking on the link *might* activate the link or it might activate the tab.  It's confusing.

See the tab pattern at https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#tabpanel and also the associated example at https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/tabs/tabs-2/tabs.html.  You'll see that they use `<button>` elements for the tabs instead of list elements.  You can use a list if you want but the element with `role="tab"` must be clickable (including via a keyboard) and shouldn't have a nested element that can also be clicked on.

Perhaps your links were supposed to be in the tab panel that displays after selecting on the tab selector?